# Start page numbering at page three together with twopage

Tags: titles, page-numbering

I can't figure out how to start the page numbering on the third page, e.g. after the title page and the contents page.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fourier}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

 \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}



 \begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 title here
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{chapter}

 \end{document}
```

This only works if I choose the option to be oneside. If I choose it to be twoside, it does not work. I haven't found any answer to this question somewhere else.

Just to be claer: I chose the documentclass "book" with the option twoside. Therfore, after the title page there is a second blank page and then the chapter starts. I would like to start the page numbering on the same page as the chapter starts. If I just add something like

```
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1},
```

then the second page, e.g. the blank page, gets the page number 2 and is displayed on this page. The third page then starts with the number 1 again. So, I just want to remove the number on the second/blank page.

Comment: Just write `\pagenumbering{arabic}`: the `\pagenumbering` command  re-initialises  the  `page` counter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.,. It does not really held, since I don't know where exactly I have to put the command. I tried a lot of things, but it did not change anything. I explained my question in more detail in the entry post

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` for the first the first part of your document and
`\pagenumbering{arabic}` for the following chapters:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{titlepage}
title here
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage% ensures that the page numbering will change on a recto page
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{chapter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\pagestyle{empty}` to begin with, then `\pagenumbering{arabic}` just before the first chapter.

Alternatively, to avoid having to write `\thispagestyle{empty}` at each blank page, you can load the `clearempty` package, or, if you use `titlesec`, add the `[clearempty]`  option.

Basic code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fourier}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
 title here
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum

 \end{document}
```